# What do you do for sun allergy?

Tags: hiking, health

My wife gets itchy hives if you stays out under the hot sun for too long. They go away within a day but is uncomfortable.

I am wondering if anyone else who loves the outdoors experiences this and what you do to prevent it. Is the only solution really just limiting sun exposure through clothing, hat and not staying out for too long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If she is actually allergic to sun then the only solution is to cover up, with clothes and sun screen.

From [Weather.com](http://www.weather.com/activities/health/allergies/relief/help_natural_pilates.html)

> As a first-line treatment, we usually ask the person to avoid the sun
>   if possible, and if they do go out in the sun to use photo-protective
>   measures. So in addition to staying in the shade, they should wear a
>   long-sleeve shirt if possible and use what we call broad-spectrum
>   sunscreen that has UVB as well as UVA blockers. If someone knows that
>   they are only sensitive to UVB, it's not as essential that they use
>   the broad-spectrum sunscreen. We ask people to look for sunscreen that
>   has SPF 15 or above because the probability of having UVB and fairly
>   good UVA protection is quite good. People should specifically look for
>   the word "broad-spectrum" on the label.

If it is heat that causes her hives then the main goal is to wear cooling clothes like light linens.

That is about all there is to it.

Comment: As someone with PLE (Polymorphic light eruption, commonly called sun allergy) the best cause of action I've been told is Factor 30 sun cream that has both UVA/UVB protection. Some forms of PLE lessen over the summer as the skin gets used to the sun again. If she has problems sweating - then it is more likely Prickly Heat and requires different treatment.